# Auto height fancybox2

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I was using fancybox plugin to one of my site. I really love using it until I encounter this problem. Inside fancybox i want to put an accordion to it. The problem is I want the fancybox height to grow and no scrollbar shown when accordion is being collapse.

please click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sunnyjaysabuero90/wufGk/) for my current code

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the height after the fancy box opens. Updated your code adding `afterShow`

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect : 'elastic',
    openSpeed  : 150,
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    closeSpeed  : 150,
    autoDimensions: true,
    height: 'auto',
    afterShow: function(){
        $.fancybox.update()
    }
});
```

Here is the working demo, http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/wufGk/1/

Comment: same idea as the first answer but much better implementation. thanks muthu.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$.fancybox.update();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wufGk/2/

Answer (score 0):

I have added the below code after height:'auto' in the below url
 http://jsfiddle.net/sunnyjaysabuero90/wufGk/, it works

```
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect : 'elastic',
        openSpeed  : 150,
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        closeSpeed  : 150,
        autoDimensions: true,
        height: 'auto',

    beforeShow: function(){
       this.width = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('html').width();
       this.height = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('html').height();
      }
        fitToView: false
    });

    $('.accordionButton').click(function() {
        $('.accordionButton').removeClass('accordionButton-open');
        $('.accordionContent').slideUp('fast');
        if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
        $(this).addClass('accordionButton-open');
        $(this).next().slideDown('fast');
        }
    });
```